# Optimize queryset with django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, query-optimization, django-queryset

I created a function that allows to count the number that there is of `status` and assign it to a variable.

```
def get_types_count_display(self):
    dispatches = self.route_dispatches.values_list('dispatch_id', flat=True)
    dispatches = Dispatch.objects.filter(id__in=dispatches)
    d = { "dispatches_types": list(dispatches.values('status_id')) }
    pendents = len([1 for e in d["dispatches_types"] if e["status_id"]==1])
    delivered = len([1 for e in d["dispatches_types"] if e["status_id"]==2])
    partial = len([1 for e in d["dispatches_types"] if e["status_id"]==3])
    undelivered = len([1 for e in d["dispatches_types"] if e["status_id"]==4])
    return dict(pendents=pendents, delivered=delivered, partial=partial, undelivered=undelivered)
```

where `d` is my variable that stores the dictionary it contains

```
{'dispatches_types': [{'status_id': 2}, {'status_id': 1}, {'status_id': 1}, {'status_id': 1}, {'status_id': 2}]}
```

or

```
{'dispatches_types': []}
```

**this is dynamic**

the problem I have is that when you go through with `for` again invoking the query set, the query becomes heavier.

How can I optimize this function?

Answer (score 1):

For 'less' queries you can use [conditional aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation). The given example is practically exactly what you are trying to do.

If the total number of Dispatch records is relatively small, loading it all at once into memory (as, say, a dictionary by calling `.values()` on the queryset) and then filtering over it might be faster than getting chunks of records per loop. I do this quite often, especially if it means avoiding instantiation of model objects.

-- seems I was too slow!

Comment: Thank you !! I've tried it that way and it does the same amount of querys: /

Comment: Without knowing the method/loop that calls `get_types_count_display` repeatedly, we can't really help you. Using the aggregation gives you the minimum amount of queries.

Comment: yes, the same thought but it does the same amount of consultations

Answer (score 0):

For this you should use [conditional aggregation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/models/conditional-expressions/#conditional-aggregation)

```
from django.db import IntegerField, Sum, Case, When

def get_types_count_display(self):
    dispatches self.route_dispatches.all()
    aggregates = dispatches.aggregate(
        pendents=Sum(Case(When(status_id=1, then=1), output_field=IntegerField())),
        delivered =Sum(Case(When(status_id=2, then=1), output_field=IntegerField())),
        partial=Sum(Case(When(status_id=3, then=1), output_field=IntegerField())),
        undelivered=Sum(Case(When(status_id=4, then=1), output_field=IntegerField()))
    )
    return aggregates
```

`aggregates` is a dict with the same values as you returned before but performed with 1 query

Comment: thank you try this way but keep making several querys

Comment: What are you talking about? Are you calling `get_types_count_display` multiple times in a single request?

Answer (score 0):

As it was said, conditional aggregation might work better here. Just wanted to add alternative query, since we don't really need to get the sum aggregation, but the count of dispatches with specified status. So it can be written the following way:

```
from django.db.models import Q


aggregates = dispatches.aggregate(
    pendents=Count('pk', filter=Q(status_id=1)),
    delivered =Count('pk', filter=Q(status_id=2)),
    partial=Count('pk', filter=Q(status_id=3)),
    undelivered=Count('pk', filter=Q(status_id=4)),
)
```

Comment: Thank you !! I've tried it that way and it does the same amount of querys: /

Comment: This is strange.. according to Django docs this should translate to one query with counts and case statements.